# first Delete \n in an array or list

Tags: python-3.x

```
I Have the following output:
['>ENST00000252519.8 ACE2-201 cdna:protein_coding\n', 'ATGGAAGTATTTAAAGCGCCACCTATTGGGATATAAG\n', '\n', '>TRENST0023525133.3 ACE2-202 cdna:protein_coding\n', 'ATGAAATTATTTAAAGCGCCACTTATTGGAATATAAA\n', 'TTGTAGCTCGATCGATCCGTACTGACTGACTGACTAA\n', 'ATGGAAGTATTTAAAGCGCCACCTATTGGGATATAAG\n']
```

and i want the output to be like:

```
['>ENST00000252519.8 ACE2-201 cdna:protein_coding', 'ATGGAAGTATTTAAAGCGCCACCTATTGGGATATAAG','>TRENST0023525133.3 ACE2-202 cdna:protein_coding','ATGAAATTATTTAAAGCGCCACTTATTGGAATATAAA', 'TTGTAGCTCGATCGATCCGTACTGACTGACTGACTAA','ATGGAAGTATTTAAAGCGCCACCTATTGGGATATAAG']
```

so the second is like the first but without \n

Comment: can u share the sample output

Comment: In the question space

Comment: sorry i didn't notice the same you change the same to code in the editor which will help high lighting the same

Comment: would you please mention out of the second one also

Comment: @carl please  proofread if the editing I did makes you happy, if not, refine it

Answer (score 0):

This is a cheap solution.

```
sq = "ENST00000252519.8 ACE2-201 cdna:protein_coding ATGGAAGTATTTAAAGCGCCACCTATTGGGATATAAG"
array = sq.split("protein_coding")
array[0] = "<" +  array[0] + "protein_coding"
```